# PHP package version not found by Composer, but it is present in my packagist page

Tags: php, composer-php

In my packagist package dashboard I see the versions

- v0.0.5
- v0.0.4
- v0.0.3
- v0.0.2
- v0.0.1

But my Composer won't find v0.0.4 and v0.0.5.

```
"Could not find package user/package in a version matching 0.0.5"
```

It's been 20 minutes since the release was pushed, still not found in Composer and this is not the first time this happens. Is this what I can expect from Packagist or am I doing something wrong? I have tried

```
composer global clearcache
composer global require user/name
composer global require user/name:version
```

Comment: Can you share package name?

Comment: Unfortunately! Thanks for interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Packagist's Twitter feed there has been some problem with the service today. I tested to update another package of mine but it could not proceed so something is funky. I'm assuming this is it and I will return to confirm tomorrow.

#### Update

Confirmed, today all is good.